# Internal data structures in Haskell (text)

Tags: haskell, bytestring

So, I'm parsing some JSON into a custom data type with aeson, and I can't seem to understand why Haskell needs to have two representations of certain types in a library.  In my case, this is all related to text.

For example:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString'
with actual type `B.ByteString'.
```

Uhm, what?  How are those two not the same? Why is there `Data.ByteString.ByteString` *and* `Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString`?  I don't understand why those two are two distinct types and why I'd need to convert between them.

Is there a guide somewhere that covers the use of ByteStrings?  I understand they are way more efficient than `String`s if you're only dealing with ASCII.

Answer (score 6):

`Data.ByteString.ByteString` is merely a reexport of `Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString`, so the types are identical. However a strict and lazy bytestrings are different types, so I suspect the problem you're experiencing to be caused by `B.ByteString` actually being `Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString`.

If that doesn't help, please provide more context.

Bytestring is indeed the most efficient type for storing ASCII. Here's [a tutorial on bytestring](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/bytestring-bits-and-pieces). `String` is very inefficient for most use cases, [`Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) is the preferred alternative for unicode.

Answer (score 2):

`Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString` is the same type as `Data.ByteString.ByteString`. I'm willing to bet larger sums of money than I have available to me that `B` is actually an import of `Data.ByteString.Lazy`.

So the error is actually that you're mixing `Data.ByteString.ByteString` with `Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString`.  The fact that the `.Internal` sneaks in there is an artifact of there not being tools to tell GHC to report a module other than the one that defined the type as the canonical location of that type in error messages.

Comment: ... and you wouldn't lose that bet :)